# How do I find the row and collumn sections enabled in an SRAM when the input address is th e binary equivalent of 1770 hex .

Tags: sram

This is the actual quesion:

```
A 16K x 8 SRAM uses coincident decoding. Determine the row and column selection lines that are enabled when the input address is the binary equivalent of 1770(hex). 

This is the answer: ROW : 112(Decimal)
                 COLLUMN: 46(Decimal)
```

Could someone please help me understand how they have gotten this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two unstated assumptions- that the matrix is square and that column is addressed by the least significant bits.

Since this is homework, I think that's enough of a hint.

Comment: Im actually studying for a final and doing some extra questions, and cant seems to figure this one out. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Write the address out in binary and split it.

Comment: 0001 0111 ///  0111 0000  This is what i have gotten

Comment: You made an error splitting it- the right hand part is correct. How many bits does it take to address each of column and row?

Comment: Its supposed to be 7 on each side. I got it now but the values seems to be swaped. The most significant 7 bits should relate to the rows and the lease significant 7 should relate to the collumns do you know if im making a mistake>

Comment: Okay, you got it then. There is no reason (other than convention) to pick one 7-bit set over the other for row or column.